# Visual Studio 2010 Not Recognizing Unit Test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

In an existing solution I added a new Test Project.  In my Test Project .cs file I have a class decorated with the [TestClass] attribute and a method decorated with the [TestMethod] attribute.  I have verified that in Configuration Manager the build check box is checked for the Test Project (as my google search has revealed was the problem for others with this issue).  I have set Test Project as my start up project for the solution.  When I try to start the test I get "Can not start test project because the project does not contain any tests".  I am really new to unit testing.  What am I missing?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
       Whole bunch of stuff
       Assert.Inconclusive("Done");
    }
 }
```

Update:  So I opened a new instance of VS, went to File => New => Project => Test Project.  Did not touch or edit anything.  Went straight to the cs file and here are its contents in its entirety:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestProject2
{
 public class Inspection
 {
    public bool SubmitInsp()
    {
        return true;
    }
 }

 [TestClass]
 public class UnitTest1
 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Inspection insp = new Inspection();
        bool result = insp.SubmitInsp();

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
 }
}
```

Same error about the project not containing any test when I try to start it. Also found this in the build output "Could not load file or assembly '~\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestProject2\bin\Debug\TestProject2.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"

I don't know that units tests get much simpler than this.  What the heck???

Comment: Can you still run the unit test by selecting it and running it? 

E.g. If you right-click on the actual test method (in your .cs file), and select to 'Run Test', does it work then?

Comment: Can you post your test class? I've ran into this before, and i believe it was a syntax issue.

Comment: @CiaranG When I do that I do not receive any errors.  But the test doesn't actually do what it should so I attempted to put a breakpoint in it to figure out why. When I try to debug, everything builds but there is an exclamation point over the breakpoint that says it will never be hit because "No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the test framework. I've worked with both the Visual Studio test framework and NUnit. There is not much difference between them. Some things have to be done a little differently, but I wouldn't change to something you are unfamiliar with. You said you were new to unit testing, so I think it's best you stick with the Visual Studio test framework because it more tightly integrates with Visual Studio. Seldary, I don't think it's constructive to be suggesting changing to another framework when the guy is trying to get to grips with the Visual Studio test framework.

Comment: Are you attempting to run the tests in 'Debug' mode or 'Release' mode?

Comment: Is it possible SP1 is causing this?  I was able to create a couple small test projects prior to installing SP1 a couple days ago.  Now none of the test projects I create will start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Projects saved to a network folder or anywhere locally on my computer have this issue.  Created another Test Project and saved it to my flash drive, works just fine.  I don't know if it is because my machine is 64 bit or because its a virtual machine or what, but I guess I just need to test everything on external storage devices.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get this to work by modifying the *devenv.exe* configuration file found here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`.

Add the following line to the `<runtime>` section, then restart Visual Studio:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled = "true" />
```

(Here is the [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650267/unit-test-adapter-threw-exception-uri-formats-are-not-suppo) that helped me)

Comment: I have my dev environment in a VMware VM atop Windows Server 2008 R2 (so it is 64 bit). My code is on a network drive (well, it's in a Shared Folder mapped to a drive letter). This hint solved my issue!

Comment: I had the same problem due to my Test Project files located on a network folder. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem, when tests in an working test project suddenly weren't recognized anymore.

Comparing the project file with one from another working test project showed me that the <ProjectTypeGuids> node was missing from the main <PropertyGroup> node.

Adding this line inside the <PropertyGroup> node solved my problem:

C#:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

VB:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [FrstCBC's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977500/244916) did not worked for me.
I am on a VirtualBox machine with Windows 7 64 bits and Visual Studio 2012.

I had to **move the output to a local folder** : open the unit tests project properties and in the **Build** tab, browse the **Output path** to a local folder. The tests are now detected and can be run.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just that my class and method weren't `public` (I realize the poster did have `public`, but I found this post by Googling "testclass testmethod margin icons missing").  Dumb mistake on my part, but maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that all the .cs files are marked as Compile in the Properties window. If it is marked as Content then you will hit this issue.